# getting error when trying to query root\virtualization namespace

Tags: windows, wmi, hyper-v

I am trying to query virtual processor class(Win32_PerfRawData_HvStats_HyperVHypervisorVirtualProcessor) from a `hyper-v server(windows 2012).`

Used this to query from powershell-

`gmic -namespace “root\virtualization” Win32_PerfRawData_HvStats_HyperVHypervisorVirtualProcessor | ElementName`.

But getting the below error:

```
gwmi : Invalid namespace "root\virtualization"
At line:1 char:1
+ gwmi -namespace “root\virtualization” Win32_PerfRawData_HvStats_HyperVHypervisor ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I have tried `root\virtualization\v2` namespace as well, but same error.

After i tried steps from `https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2014/08/08/wmi-repository-corruption-or-not/`, figured out that, "virtualization" namespace does not exist in my server. I tried online to find mof file virtualization namespace,but couldn't find any result.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

`root\virtualization` and `root\virtualization\v2` namespaces are present only on `Hyper-v servers`. You don't need any MOF here. Just connect to Hyper-V namespace and query.

I am guessing that you are trying queries from a machine which does not have Hyper-V.

```
$cred= Get-Credential  #Credential of Hyper-V server
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\virtualization" -Class Win32_PerfRawData_HvStats_HyperVHypervisorVirtualProcessor -ComputerName <Hyper-V server> -Credential $cred | Select ElementName
```

**Updated**

Run below mentioned powershell script to know Hyper-V server

```
 (get-item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters").GetValue("HostName")
```

Comment: No, i have a machine with hyper-v only.  I ran this "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem  WHERE Model LIKE '%Virtual%'", and it returned me "Virtual Machine", which says , its hyper v.

Comment: This means your machine is "Virtual Machine" which is hosted on Hyper-V, it does not mean it is Hyper-V itself.

Comment: Running the above script (get-item*) returns me a machine name (xxx-hypv-test-01). As far as i know, this is a Windows 2012R2 VM running on Hyper-V.

Comment: That machine will have virtualization MOFs. You have to connect with respect to that machine. It means your current machine is hosted on xxx-hypv-test-01. Are your both machine same?

Comment: Yes, both are same.

Comment: I went to server manager dashboard the checked the features, as well. when i try to select "Hyper-v" feature from the feature set, getting a message saying, "hypervisor is already running"

Comment: Also, running "gcim Win32_ComputerSystem).HypervisorPresent" is returning True. 

PS C:\Windows\System32\wbem> (gcim Win32_ComputerSystem).HypervisorPresent

True

Comment: Just to be clear, 

1. Your hyper-v server is xxx-hypv-test-01

2. Machine you want to get information is xxx-hypv-test-01

Comment: If Yes, i don't have a clue how are you missing MOFs, you can recreate your repository and try. Internally, Hyper-V also uses these MOFs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115750/discussion-between-amit-shakya-and-venkataratnam).